# Configurable mail server mock for JUnit tests?

Tags: java, email, junit, mocking, jakarta-mail

I'm looking for a mail server mock that can be configured like a Mockito mock object.
Currently we are using [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/) as mail server mock, but I would like to do something like this in my unit tests:

> - if mail with subject xyz arrives, accept.
> - if mail with subject zz1 arrives, send temporarily failure
> - if mail with subject fh2 arrives, send bounce (unknown recipient).
> - .....

As I can see, [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/) is not capable of this.
Does anyone knows a library which can do something like this?

Comment: Look for Subetha SMTP library. http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally i extended greenmail with the functionallity to close smtp server after x mails or skip acceptance of smtp connection after x mails and to slow down the smtp handling for a specific mail.
Thanks for the answers.
Its possible that i'm allowed to push my changes back to greenmail trunk. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I've used "dumbster" (http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/) in the past and it's worked well.  I just checked the javadoc and I don't see any configurable ability to accept/reject messages based on arbitrary criteria, but it is open source so it might be straightforward to add this capability.

Answer (score 0):

Someone I know use this succesfully in his codebase. It's basically updated link from Usman Saleem's comment on the question above.

https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp/blob/master/Wiser.md